# How to find the unique access log IPs

Tags: linux, ip

I need to get all the IPs which accessed my server today only. From below command I could get all the IPs ,but I need to get the IPs of today only..

```
sudo awk '{ print $1}' /etc/httpd/logs/access_log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

I need to `grep '20/Apr'` from `acccess_log`. Can someone help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In begin of `awk` you can add:

```
sudo awk '/20\/Apr/ { print $1}' /etc/httpd/logs/access_log
```

this will search for lines with `20/Apr` in them as string

Comment: Thank you..Its great. Have a good day